# How to design a TabPage without TabControl?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to design some "standalone" tab-pages and later on, I want to add them dynamically to a tab-control in my main form. Visual Studio won't let me open the class extended with `TabPage` in the designer. Some idea?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test.View.Panels {

    public class MainStatusTabPage : TabPage {

        public MainStatusTabPage() {
            
        }

    }
}
```

When I right-click the class in the Solution Explorer and selecting "View Designer", I get the following message (the Designer doesn't show up):

> To add components to your class, drag them from the Toolbox and use
> the Properties window to set their properties. To create methods and
> events for your class, switch to code view.

Comment: Can you please show us the code in question to be able to replicate this Also `I am having Java background and there I was able to extend some class with e.g. JPanel which I then could open in the IDE designer` has nothing to do with a `TabPage` and or `Visual Studio`, it's irrelevant to this post.

Comment: Okay I added my code. Removed references to Java.

Comment: that's normal behavior, it's not an issue. A `TabPage` is just a panel (or as they call it, a container).

Comment: But is there a way to visually design "stand-alone" tab-pages and add them later on dynamically to a tab-control with C#, WinForms and Visual Studio?

Comment: `But is there a way to design "stand-alone" tab-pages`, no. What you *can* do is create a user control with everything you would need on that tabpage and create a new instance of it and then add it to the tabpage. Think of the tabpage as just a container (because that's what it is), there's no design time support, it just holds other controls.

Comment: A Tab Page is a *container*, not the actual content of the tab. In all examples that use complex content you'll see that the content is a custom component, eg a User control, that's added into the tab

Comment: In fact, the [OS UI element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tab-controls) is just the tabs and a [single display area](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tab-controls#display-area). The display area remains the same. What changes is the controls displayed in that area, in response to click events

Comment: Thanks, that's the information I needed. So I will have to use a `UserControl`.

Comment: @salocinx yes, that's best.

Comment: @salocinx and technically, you only need one tab page class to be honest (no need for multiple ones; have a base tabpage class), use `usercontrols` to slap into the instance of the tabpage.

Comment: @salocinx for more reasons that this. You really don't want your control to depend on the layout you use. If you decided to change tab controls for something fancier, you'd have to copy all the contents and rewrite your code. If you inherited from `TabPage` you wouldn't be able to change layout styles at all.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `If you decided to change tab controls for something fancier, you'd have to copy all the contents and rewrite your code. If you inherited from TabPage you wouldn't be able to change layout styles at all`, this is a great point.

Comment: Thanks for all that useful input! So I basically have one `TabControl` with some `TabPage`s and then I add my `UserControl` instances, which I can design with the IDE designer, to the individual `TabPage`s. The "namespace" for my fields are independent/encapsulated between these `UserControl`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I right-click the class in the Solution Explorer and selecting "View Designer", I get the following message (the Designer doesn't show up):
> *To add components to your class, drag them from the Toolbox and use the Properties window to set their properties. To create methods and events for your class, switch to code view*.

This is normal behavior as a `TabPage` is just a container that holds other controls, nothing more. As @PanagiotisKanavos mentioned [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64209380/how-to-design-a-tabpage-without-tabcontrol/64209857#):

> A Tab Page is a container, not the actual content of the tab. In all examples that use complex content you'll see that the content is a custom component, eg a User control, that's added into the tab

With this in mind, you can just create a `UserControl` with all the other controls you would need and then add this new instance (UserControl) to the `TabPage` itself.